# Unit Tests inheritance

Tags: unit-testing

How do i make Base class with [TestClass()], where i will do MyClassInitialize(), and after that, i will just make my another Test classes just like that - MyNewTest : BaseTest
and there will no initializing?

Comment: It seems you are using C# (and NUnit?) - please specify.

Comment: I would question the motives behind such a move. Unit tests are supposed to be short lived and *simple*. If you hide initialization there is a possibility that they will be brittle and difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(using MSTest)

The ClassInitialize won’t work on a base class.  It seems that this attribute is searched for only on the executed test class.  However, you can call the base class explicitly.

Here is an example:

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass : TestBase
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void MyTestMethod()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("MyTestMethod");
    }

    [ClassInitialize]
    public new static void MyClassInitialize(TestContext context)
    {
        TestBase.MyClassInitialize(context);
    }
}

[TestClass]
public abstract class TestBase
{
    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

    public static void MyClassInitialize(TestContext context)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("MyClassInitialize");
    }

    [AssemblyInitialize]
    public static void AssemblyInit(TestContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In NUnit/MbUnit you simply put the Initalize/Cleanup methods with the respective attributes in the base class, then inherit from it.

I haven't tried this yet with MSTest, but I wouldn't recommend this framework anyway.

Thomas